# High frequency sound on a PWM fan for some specific duty settings

Tags: fan, component-failure, acoustic-noise

So I got a used fan (specifically a Sanyo Denki 9s1212 series) and I discovered that under most duty settings (practically when not 100% or 0%) the fan emits a high frequency sound like this: (mind your volume settings before and after watching these links!).

[High frequency noise example](https://i.imgur.com/QaNTjlK.mp4)

[No mentioned high frequency noise, only normal motor and wind noise, if full duty](https://i.imgur.com/gAsmcsu.mp4)

By the way the noise is absent if I were to connect only 9v instead of rated 12v for VCC.

I've changed the ball bearings, plus the sound persists even if the fan blades are not moving, hence I assume this should've been because some passive components on the PCB is failing, but unfortunately neither do I know how to debug exactly what component is failing nor it seems I could tear apart the PCB since there seems to be some black glue securing the PCB to the shaft.

Any suggestions on how I can repair this exact model of fan?

Comment: How many wires, 3 or 4?

Comment: It's a 4 pin model, with GND, VCC, tachometer, and pwm control. The 2 videos I linked in the post are both using 12v VCC but with different duty, the longer with high freq. noise one is around 50%, while the shorter without high freq. buzz one is 100% duty. As mentioned, with 12v VCC, the fan almost always emits the high freq. noise unless the duty is set to either full or none.

Comment: What is the PWM source? Btw, thanks for the heads up about the volume.

Comment: What’s your PWM frequency?

Comment: Arduino nano with TIMER2 registers (OCR2A/B, TCCR2A/B, etc) set to s.t. PWM is 25k which is specified by most fan manufacturers including Sanyo Denki. I asked another question on Arduino forum and in that post I've provided corresponding code sketch. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reading-tachometers/1167658

Comment: Just the other day I found half a dozen young folk who could hear 25 KHz. Most cannot hear it. I suspect the frequency is lower than you calculated by a factor of 2 or 4.

Comment: Wow, I guess you're right.

Turns out I used the formula for fast pwm when deciding value for `OCR2A` register, while in fact my code puts the Arduino Nano in phase correct pwm mode. On Arduino Nano Atmega328p, this means that the pwm output is wrongly set to around 12.5k instead of the required 25k.

Now I'm with the following setting: `TCCR2A = _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM20)`, `TCCR2B__ = _BV(CS21) | _BV(WGM22)`, and `OCR2A = 40`, which I believe is the right settings to produce 25k pwm signal, and this change did mitigate much of the annoying high frequency buzz.

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested, here's before & after noise sample and FFT. Again, be sure to check volume before & after visiting these links.

[Original, wrong OCR2A (79), around 12.5k pwm instead of 25k](https://i.imgur.com/6e7a3Qg.mp4)
[New, supposedly correct OCR2A (40), around 25k pwm](https://i.imgur.com/3LMMQdz.mp4)

Comment: @RussellH would you like to post an answer s.t. I could mark the problem as solved? This problem should be as simple as that I fed wrong frequency, `16M/(2*79*8)~=12658`, instead of the required `25000` to the pwm control input of the fan. Thx for everyone!

Comment: On hindsight maybe you all have hinted that I may had set pwm frequency wrong, but I just didn't understand. Thank all of you guys again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the other day I found half a dozen young folk who could hear 25 KHz. Most cannot hear it. I suspect the frequency is lower than you calculated by a factor of 2 or 4.